# How to save Joost.com Videos?

Tags: video

Is there any way / software to save Joost.com videos into my physical drive?
Firefox Download Helper addon does not work for Joost videos.

Answer (score 4):

Haven't tried it recently but [stream transport](http://www.streamtransport.com/) did work for me.

Comment: I tried and it works! Great find. +1.

Comment: Are you sure? 
When I tried it,it gives me "Sorry,the video you wanted to see is unavailable." error.

Comment: Yes I am. I randomly selected a Joost video, and it downloaded it (2.6 MB), renamed it as flv, and saved on my hard disk. Maybe the video you tried was problematic, try the others.

Comment: With which video did you succeed? I can try and see the result...

Comment: This [one](http://www.joost.com/3c41vt8t/).

Comment: It does not work...
"Sorry, the video you wanted to see is unavailable"

Comment: This is strange... It works here. Just retried to make sure.

Answer (score 0):

I've used [Orbit Downloader](http://www.orbitdownloader.com/) with some success in the past.